# explicite wait is not working correctly, even if element is loaded still it take significant time to proceed further execution

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, wait

**My Code**

```
/**
         * This method will explicit wait for an element to be visible.
         * @param element
         *            element
         * @param timeOut
         *            timeout in seconds
         */
        @Override
        public void explicitWaitForElement(String element, int timeOut) {
            try {
                LOGGER.debug("In explicitWaitForElement Finction");
                String locator = getConstantValue(element);
                LOGGER.debug("locator constant Value : " , locator);
                setWait(getWebDriver(), timeOut);
                getWait().until(
                        ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By
                                .xpath(locator)));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                LOGGER.error(
                        "Within explicitWaitForElement - Element not found until timeout:",
                        e);
            }
        }

/**
 * This method will explicit wait for an element to be visible.
 * 
 * @param element
 *            element
 * @param timeOut
 *            timeout in seconds
 */
@Override
public void explicitWaitForEleDisappers(String element, int timeOut) {
    try {
        LOGGER.debug("In explicitWaitForEleDisappers Finction");
        String locator = getConstantValue(element);
        LOGGER.debug("locator constant Value : " , locator);
        setWait(getWebDriver(), timeOut);
        getWait().until(
                ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By
                        .xpath(locator)));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error(
                "Within explicitWaitForElement - Element not found until timeout:",
                e);
    }
}
```

and `Setter` for wait:

```
 /**
 * Setter for wait.
 * 
 * @param timeOut timeout
 * @param wd webDriver
 */ 
public void setWait(WebDriver wd, int timeOut) {
    this.wait = new WebDriverWait(wd, timeOut);
    this.wait.ignoring(StaleElementReferenceException.class, WebDriverException.class);
}
```

- Getter for wait.

  - - @return wait value
      */
      public WebDriverWait getWait() {
      return wait;
      }

Comment: Add some explanation too

Comment: Can you please suggest any improvment to the given script so that once the element found it will move to execute next code without holding any time. Here i have passed the Locator as Xpah (e.g. //span[@class='xyz'][.='test']))

Comment: Parameter passed :  element = Locator(xpath of WebElement , timeout in Second).

Comment: Why dont you use WebDriverWait ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is `WebDriverWait` functionality in selenium, you can set explicit wait. You are using selenium webdriver, then it is far better to use `WebDriverWait` for waiting purpose to element. follow below code

```
protected WebElement waitForPresent(final String locator, long timeout) {
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeout);
    WebElement ele = null;
    try {
        ele = wait.until(ExpectedConditions
                .presenceOfElementLocated(locator));
    } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
    }
    return ele;
}

protected WebElement waitForNotPresent(final String locator, long timeout) {
    timeout = timeout * 1000;
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    WebElement ele = null;
    while ((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) < timeout) {
        try {
            ele = findElement(locator);
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return ele;
}
```

Comment: import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait; just it, functionality of selenium. Answer updated.

Comment: I have already used WebdriverWait and setting explisite wait time in setter Method, But It still pause for some time even thought the element is visible  on the page. I tried your code but issue still persist.

Comment: Tell me which kind of issue you are facing on my code? Have you error-log?

Comment: Sanjay, its not a kind of Error/issue, the problem with code is like its taking some time to execute the next line of code even if that element is present on the UI. e. g. Consider on Click I am looking for Certain WebElement, Its displayed in two Second on UI, but  waitForPresent(final String locator, long timeout) method took 6-8 Sec. I am not getting why this difference is getting even though the element is already loaded. This is happening for all WebElement.